# How quickly should I accept answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes I receive answers that would solve my problem, and seem plausible, but I don't know whether they're correct, or if they're the full story.

Should I accept such answers immediately? Or should I wait a day or so until they've received some upvotes (hopefully not just everyone else saying [I don't know if this is correct or not, but it makes sense to me](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/how-can-we-objectively-judge-an-answers-credibility)!) and no comments or disagreeing answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are [recommended to eventually accept one answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) unless there is a good reason not to do so.

However, you do not have to accept an answer as soon as possible.  I think that it is generally a good idea to wait for one day or two before accepting any answer.  This way, other people can post a counter-statement if they find anything wrong with the answer.

It is not a good idea to wait indefinitely until your are convinced of the correctness of an answer.  If it takes a long time for you to be convinced, there may be something wrong with either your question or the posted answer.  If the answer lacks a verifiable source, it makes a perfect sense to ask for one by posting a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting is up to you.
You have no duty to accept answers that satisfy other people.
If you never get a satisfying answer, then

- the question is too vague,
- the question is too hard,
- the question is too localised,
- the question needs more time, or
- many possible other answers.

If you think you'll never have a satisfying answer, well, then, maybe it's ok to *never* accept any answer, but then, maybe the question should be tagged as "open-problem"…

Comment: Also, bounties can be used if you don't like any of the existing answers.